# how to keep the selected checkbox when the form is close?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

i got some checkbox and i want to retain the selected ones when i reopen the form.
here's what i done almost but it only returns the very first selected checkbox only..

```
For Each strItm As String In str
        For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
                If ctl.Text = strItm Then
                    Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox)
                    cb.Checked = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

and anyone help me out. tnx in advance. more power.

Comment: a list (of string)..hmmmm i already done this..tnx btw..

Comment: the answer depends on what "reopen the form" means.  the answer is different if you mean run the app again vs reloading a form

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to create a global bool variable for each check box that holds true when its check box is checked and false when it's not. Then when you close your form those variables will keep their values. Once you re-open the form you can set the checked property back matching those variables through the form Load event

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    checkbo1.checked = globalVar1
    checkbo2.checked = globalVar2
    checkbo3.checked = globalVar3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `ParentForm`:

```
Dim frm As New ChildForm
frm.ShowDialog()
```

In the `ChildForm`

```
Public Shared Chk1 As Boolean

Private Sub ChildForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     CheckBox1.Checked = Chk1
End Sub
```

Also you need to update the vaule here when changed:

```
If ctl.Text = strItm Then
    Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox)
    cb.Checked = True
    Chk1 = True
End If
```